Selenium на ubuntu 24.04?
Хочу перейти с Windows на linux (пока выбрал ubuntu). Очень важно использовать selenium с python3. Будет ли какая-то разница?
Так же вопрос по профилю для google chrome: я могу перенести appdata от chrome, чтобы не перенастраивать профили снова?

Виртуалку в руки и вперёд пробовать

С селениум проблем нет. Единственное что поломали установку пип в юзера, но виртуалэнв работает хорошо.
Профиль в appdata у меня ни разу не перенесся нормально. Но есть же синхронизация.
